# VTT Subtitles on Chromecast with MP4 Video

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I am trying to get closed captions to work with my ChromeCast custom receiver application. I have added CORS headers to my CDN. However, I am running into roadblocks getting captions to load properly with MP4 video files when those captions are hosted on a different bucket than where my receiver application resides. The captions load properly when they are hosted with the same origin as the receiver application, as is done in [this example app](https://github.com/googlecast/CastClosedCaptioning-chrome).

My sender application passes information to enable captions via the following message:

```
session.sendMessage('urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.sample.closecaption', message, 
onSuccess, onError);
```

My receiver application, upon receiving this message, creates or replaces a track element on the receiver html specifying the proper source.

```
trackElement.src = tracks[activeTrackLanguage];
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Cross-origin text track load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy.
```

After doing a bit of research I discovered the `crossorigin` attribute for video elements. So, in my receiver debug console I wrote the following **after my mp4 video was already loaded**:

```
document.getElementById('player').setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
```

Then, I sent the enable captions message with the caption I wanted to play and it worked! Unfortunately, having the `crossorigin` property seems to be preventing proper loading of my MP4 video content, because I get the following error when trying to load my video:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'https://mysite.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

This error loading my MP4 video only arises when I add this attribute to my video element. Are subtitles/captions supported for mp4 video? Do I need to add the `crossorigin` attribute after my video loads, and then remove shortly after my vtt loads? Seems a bit hacky. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

CORS need to be configured on the server side where you are hosting your video and your tracks.

Comment: is it possible to get the CastRecieverPlayer to add a vtt file to a video without hosting it? just download the vtt and insert?

Comment: You still need to host is somewhere to be able to download it.